# Audit Database Log On/Off

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, audit

SQL Server 2012 introduced a few new audit action groups.  Two that I'm interested in using are to audit log-ons/offs at the database level:

```
SUCCESSFUL_DATABASE_AUTHENTICATION_GROUP
DATABASE_LOGOUT_GROUP
```

The problem is, I also have SQL Server 2008 R2 instances that I'd like to deploy this on.  Are there alternatives to achieve this using native SQL Server Audit?  Or do I have to do this by other means (eg. SQL Profiler Trace, Logon/logoff triggers)?

Comment: Does someone who connects to master and then runs a query that references a table in databaseX ever "log on" to databaseX? If that query references tables in databases Y and Z, do you expect log on events happen on all three databases? If a user has a default database of X they'll always log on there but then may only work in other databases. Outside of contained databases and Azure SQL Database, I feel like logging on is something that happens at the instance level, not the database level, and if the log on only happens for the original db it doesn't hold a lot of value for auditing purposes.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand:  Thanks!  To answer your 1st question: sometimes they do, especially if it's an ad-hoc query being executed in SSMS & they change the db context manually, no?  I get what you're saying how it doesn't hold a lot of value but would like to capture 'all' log on events, such as the scenario mentioned above, for auditing purposes.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server 2012 introduced database-level logon/logoff audit tracking as part of the "contained databases" feature, which allows SQL Server logins to be defined at the *database* level.  In prior versions of SQL Server there is no such concept of login or logout at the *database* level.

From the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-action-groups-and-actions):

> SUCCESSFUL_DATABASE_AUTHENTICATION_GROUP
> Indicates that a principal successfully logged in to a **contained** database. Equivalent to the Audit Successful Database Authentication Event Class.
>
> DATABASE_LOGOUT_GROUP
> This event is raised when a contained database user logs out of a database. Equivalent to the Audit Database Logout Event Class.

Be aware that unless you are using contained databases, and connections are being made to those databases via contained logins, those audits will not reflect login/logout events.

SQL Server Audit on 2008 R2 includes the ability to audit successful and failed logins at the *server* level via:

```
SUCCESSFUL_LOGIN_GROUP
FAILED_LOGIN_GROUP
```

Alternatively, you can configure "Login Auditing" on the "Security" tab of the "Server Properties" dialog.

In SSMS, right-click the server name in the "Object Explorer" panel.  Then choose "Properties" from the list.  Select the "Security" page, then specify "Both failed and successful logins" from the "Login auditing" section.

[image]

Login audit entries are written to the SQL Server Error Log; you can view them with this command:

```
EXEC sys.xp_readerrorlog 0, 1, 'Login';
```